# Let $D$ and $E$ be points on $AB$ and $BC$ of $\Delta ABC$ such that $AD = 7BD$ , $BE = 10CE$ . Let $AE$ and $BC$ meet at point $F$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> Let $D$ and $E$ be points on segments of $AB$ and $BC$ of $\Delta ABC$ such that $AD = 7BD$ , $BE = 10CE$ . Let $AE$ and $BC$ meet at point $F$. If $AF = k \cdot FE$ , find $[k]$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

The first thing which I did was to try the process in Geogebra. There I got the value of $k$ to be approximately $7.74$ , so $[k] = 7,$ and I think that should be the answer. I also think that the initial value of $k$ varies, but $[k]$ is always $7$ . How will I be able to come up with a solution then?

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: do you know melanaus theorem?

Comment: Heard about it, isn't it like ceva's theorem?

Comment: see https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Menelaus%27_Theorem

Comment: Already saw it in brilliant, but how do you use Menelaus Theorem, or Ceva's Theorem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:Use Menelaus theorem in $\Delta ABE$ you will get result directly

> $$\frac{BC}{CE}*\frac{EF}{FA}*\frac{AD}{DB}=1$$

About Menelaus https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Menelaus%27_Theorem

Comment: Aah, I got it. Nice.

Comment: In the end I am getting $EF = \frac{FA}{77}$ , am I missing something?

Comment: @Anonymous yes you are you haev forgotten a 1/10

Comment: @Anonymous sorry i edit

Comment: Got it now. It was BC/CE .

Comment: yeah thanks for pinting mistake that is the problem with Menelaus theorem, i get confused

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Nice! Btw I too got confused in keeping the ratios in order :)

Comment: @MathLover thanks! in some books we have to remember the order  so thet RHS becomes  -1, its a bit confusing how do you remember it

Answer (score 1):

Use [mass points method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_point_geometry).

Place masses $70$ at $B$, $10$ at $A$, $7$ at $C$.

This gives $77$ at $E$ implying

$$ \dfrac{AF}{FE}= 7.7$$

Comment: Ok, any other way which we can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Say $\angle BCD = \theta$.

Using Sine Law in $\triangle BCD$,

$\frac{\sin (\angle BDC)}{11y} = \frac{\sin \theta}{x}$ ...(i)

In $\triangle CEF$,

$\frac{\sin (\angle EFC)}{10y} = \frac{\sin \theta}{EF}$ ..(ii)

In $\triangle ADF$,

$\frac{\sin (\angle AFD)}{7x} = \frac{\sin \angle ADC}{AF}$ ..(iii)

$\angle ADC = 180^0 - \angle BDC$ (same sine value) and $\angle EFC = \angle AFD$

Substituting and solving, we get $\frac{AF}{FE} = \frac{77}{10}$